# biblatex not recognizing references (but does in Overleaf)

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

A document in Overleaf compiles fine with references. However, using the same compiler locally yields "Citation x on page n undefined (...)", and the references are not showing, only the bracket with the labels: [**label**]

Using biblatex as so:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{}
yoyo \cite{kniberg2015}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

with `references.bib`:

```
@book{kniberg2015,
    title     = {Scrum and XP from the trenches - How we do Scrum},
    author    = {H. Kniberg},
    year      = {2015},
    publisher = {C4Media}
}
```

As mentioned, this works fine in Overleaf.
I do have biblatex installed locally.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did yoou run the normal cycle: `pdflatex -> biber -> pdflatex (twice)`?

Comment: Works. Thanks! Was not aware that I had to do this..